# Is the functor $\Gamma_*$ exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\mathrm{Proj}(S)$ be a projective scheme where $S$ is a graded ring which is finitely generated by $S_1$ as an $S_0$-algebra. Let $$0 \to \mathcal{F}_1 \to \mathcal{F}_2 \to \mathcal{F}_3 \to 0$$ be a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves. Does this imply that $$0 \to \Gamma_*\mathcal{F}_1 \to \Gamma_*\mathcal{F}_2 \to \Gamma_*\mathcal{F}_3 \to 0$$ is exact as well? If not is there any condition on $X$ for which this will hold true?

Comment: It's not even true for $\Gamma$. You basically need that all the Ext^1's vanish, which is never true for a projective scheme (except for the point). Even for affine schemes, it is only true if the ring is semi-simple.

Comment: @Merci: This is not a comment. It is an answer.

Comment: I want something more sophisticated for an answer.:) What I wrote is just a comment.:)